# iptables back to previous state after reboot

Tags: centos, iptables

Im on CentOS 5.5 64 bit.I've added some rules in iptables as usual.

all changes has been saved with `sudo service iptables save` and all rules added by using command line

but after reboot, all the rules back to previous state.
this not happen on my previous server running centos 32 bit.

How to make the changes persistent?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably running some other firewall service instead of the stock `iptables` service, so your rules are not being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Put the changes in /etc/sysconfig/iptables.

The /etc/init.d/iptables script applies this file using iptables-restore.

Comment: I've already made this, but not works for my server

Comment: Have a look at /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config. It contains settings that affect the backup/restore of rules upon firewall restart. By default save on stop/restart should be set to no. What is the "previous state" of your firewall ? Empty ? BTW "service iptables save" makes use of /etc/sysconfig/iptables and /etc/sysconfig/iptables.save, which are empty if your firewall is deactivated. Use system-config-security-tui to enable it and have a look at the generated files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cd /etc/sysconfig
copy iptables my-iptables
```

Then edit `my-iptables` with your rules.  Then, as root:

```
iptables-restore < my-ip-tables
```

When you need to edit your iptables in future, edit `my-iptables` and use `iptables-restore` to do the update.

See also [iptables-howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) which mentions `iptables-save` as an alternative method for updating, which may be closer to what you tried to do already.  However, I think having a separate file for making changes is better than editing iptables file directly.